# Global Enviromental Variables for cucumber-jvm & selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I write automated tests for websites.I'm using cucumber-jvm and selenium webdriver.
I want to have something like configs in my project.

For example imagine I want to test two website's autorization. Everything is same on this two website.
for example in my feature I have two cases - Successful autorization and boundary check of Username field.

Imagine my feature file looks like this :

```
Scenario: User enters valid parameters ....
Given  User is on main page 
When   User enters "username" as "username"
When   User enters "Test@123" as "password" 
#Then   do something

Scenario: User tries to enter more than 20 characters in username field 
Given User is on main page 
When  User enters "30" characters as "username" 
Then  text length in the "username" field should be "20"
```

But username and password are different for websites.Also max length of username field is different.I want the following:

```
Scenario: User enters valid parameters 
Given  User is on main page 
When   User enters "@username" as "username"
When   User enters "@password" as "password" 
#Then   do something

Scenario: User tries to enter more than 20 characters in username field 
Given User is on main page 
When  User enters "30" characters as "username" 
Then  text length in the "username" field should be "@max_length_username"
```

And When I change my website,I want to only change some file,where this global variables are defined.

Also in my code for example I've @given method

```
public void user_is_on_Registration_page() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://website.test");
    username.sendKeys("username");
    password.sendKeys("Test123");
}
```

I want to change it to method :

```
public void user_is_on_Registration_page() throws Exception {
    driver.get(website);
    username.sendKeys(username);
    password.sendKeys(password);
}
```

I want a file where I can set all configs and variables and use them in my .java and .feature files.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the websites tested together or separately? If separately, then u can set a system property or something similar with the website identifier under test. Create a class with logic to access the actual keys and values from the appropriate config file based on the system property. Pass the value from the feature file to this class to get the actual value.

Comment: Thanks Grasshoper,I did it like your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer,it's not best approach, but it works.

I have class variables.

```
public class Variables {
 public String valid_username = "someusername";
 public String valid_password = "Test@123";
 public Map<String,String> variables = new HashMap<String,String>();
 public Variables(){
     variables.put("valid_username",valid_username);
     variables.put("valid_password",valid_password);
  }
 public String getVariable(String key){
     return variables.get(key);  
 }
 }
```

It's configs. 
In feature I have step:

```
  When User enters "valid_username" as username
  And User enters "valid_password" as password
```

That's all. Then in my step definitons I just call

```
variables.getVariable(arg1);  //arg1 is "valid_username" from feature file
```

Comment: humm. how "Global" this approach is?
I mean, this way you can share variable between steps where you have instantiated the Variables class right? But how can I do if I want to share variables between steps of different classes? Maybe with a static modifier?